# don't understand why this code doesn't work?

Tags: c++

I wanted to try one example with "implicit pointer" but don't understand why this code doesn't work?

```
#include <iostream>
    
    class Template
    {
    private:
        int x;
    public:
        void SetValue(Template* this, int value)
        {
            this->x = value;
            std::cout << "Value is " << this->x << std::endl;
        }
    };
    
    int main()
    {
        setlocale(0, "");

        Template temp;
        temp.SetValue(6); 

        std::cin.get();
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

`this` is a reserved keyword and you are not passing a pointer when calling the method.

Also, you are expecting two parameters in `SetValue` but only one is needed (why `Template* this`?)

Switch to

```
    void SetValue(int value)
    {
        this->x = value; // or simply `x = value;`
        std::cout << "Value is " << this->x << std::endl;
    }
```

If you want to pass `temp` as a pointer:

```
void SetValue(Template* self, int value)
```

and call it using

```
temp.SetValue(&temp, 6);
```

now you can use the pointer

```
self->x = value;
std::cout << "Value is " << self->x << std::endl;
```

but it doesn't make much sense in this case, note that class members are always available in its methods without using `this` nor passing a pointer to the object so in this context `this` is not useful, it is useful when you want to disambiguate a variable name that shadows some member of the class, i.e.:

```
    void SetValue(int x)
    {
        this->x = x;
        std::cout << "Value is " << this->x << std::endl;
    }
```

Comment: I was told that this is an implicit method, but it is also possible explicitly, namely Template * this

Comment: @Quuely explicitly, it is not possible, unless you explicitly pass it too, and David Ranieri has shown. That just seems very redundant though.